# Calculating attribute that contains multiple values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes

My layer contains the following fields:

- `"B"` is the identifier of a geometry
- `"B_N"` are the identifiers of the neighboring geometries of `"B"`.
- `"H"` characterizes `"B"`
- `"B_N_H"` characterizes the `"B_N"`(s)

How could I do the subtraction of `"H"` and `"B_N_H"` for each `"B_N"`?

For example:
for b = 56, I would like to get in one column "0, 1, 3, 0" and in another column the maximum value 3 and the corresponding `"b_n"` identifier 57
for b = 57, I would like to get "0, -3, 0, -1" and the maximum value 3 (absolute value) and the corresponding b_n identifier 56.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(QGIS 3.22) You can use an expression like this on a `Text` field in the Field Calculator. It makes an array from the list of neighbours, iterates through that array and subtracts each value from the `h` field. Finally, it converts the resulting array to a string to be entered in the calculated field.

```sql
array_to_string(                   -- convert the final array to a string
    array_foreach(                 -- iterate through array
        string_to_array("b_n_h"),  -- make an array from the contents of "b_n_h" field
        "h" - @element             -- for each element of the b_n_h array, subtract it from the value in field "h"
    ) 
)
```

[image]

For the other column:

```sql
"b" || ',' ||                             -- concatenate the value from "b" field with a , and the maximum absolute value as follows

array_max(                                -- get the maximum of the absolute values
    array_foreach( 
        string_to_array("subtraction"),  -- convert the string field value to an array
        abs(@element)                     -- get the absolute value of each array element
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Matt, the 1st part works perfectly. The 2nd part is more complicated: the array_max function is only available from the Qgis 3.18 version. As I am on my personal PC, I just installed version 3.22. The ok button activates, the preview of the result appears at the launch of the command, I have an error message : "An error occurred while evaluating the calculation chain: Unable to convert '' to duplicate".

what version of Qgis do you have?

Comment: I added the my version (3.22) to my answer. Do you have NULL values in one of your fields? I don't know where the error would come from otherwise

Comment: As much for me, I removed all the lists with zeros and it worked perfectly! Congratulations and thank you